# Meteor.call returns 'undefined' result when the variable is defined on server

Tags: node.js, post, asynchronous, methods, meteor

Can somebody see in my code why the variable `oauthToken` is defined on the server but not defined when returned to the client in the result of Meteor.call

I make a call to initiate a post request on the server

The body is parsed and I store a value into the variable oauthToken

This prints out on the server but does not print out on the client in my 'result'

Is this because the client is running a simulation? Can we do a 'return' in an asynchronous function?

Server.js

```
Meteor.methods({
 getGoodreads: function () { 
 request.post('http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/request_token', {oauth:{
                 consumer_key: '89hdg8pEoMzRdg',
                 consumer_secret: 'dfgdfgHthtdtjtt' }}, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              var a = querystring.parse(body)
              oauthToken = a.oauth_token
              console.log(oauthToken); //prints value i need
              return oauthToken
       }else{
              console.log('there is an error ' + error);
            }
   });
} 
});
```

client.js

```
Template.profile.events({
    'click #goodreads': function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Meteor.call('getGoodreads', function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('this is an error ');
            } else {
                console.log(result); //THIS IS UNDEFINED...possibilities?
            }
        });
    }
 });
```

Comment: Is the method defined only on the server? If I'm not mistaken, it must be defined both on the client and the server

Comment: The above might be true only if you want latency compensation

Comment: The server request is asynchronous, so the method is actually returning immediately. This looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876325/meteor-how-to-return-data-from-the-server-using-meteor-call?rq=1).

Comment: You might be better off putting the result from the request into a publication, then subscribing to the publication on the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use futures to return values from async functions:

```
var Future = Npm.require("fibers/future")    
Meteor.methods({
     getGoodreads: function () { 
     var f = new Future();
     request.post('http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/request_token', {oauth:{
                     consumer_key: '89hdg8pEoMzRdg',
                     consumer_secret: 'dfgdfgHthtdtjtt' }}, function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                  var a = querystring.parse(body)
                  oauthToken = a.oauth_token
                  console.log(oauthToken); //prints value i need
                  return f.return(oauthToken)
           }else{
                  f.throw(error);
                  console.log('there is an error ' + error);
                }
       });
       return f.wait()
    } 
    });
```

Comment: I've never used futures before, but wouldn't every path in the inner callback need to do a f.return()? I mean, the future is waiting for something to happen...

Comment: @Christain - I added 'future' at version 2.3.1 and called the package into my project as you wrote 'var future = Npm.require("fibers/future")' ...and this works. The oauthToken gets passed back to the client and is defined in the result! Thanks

Comment: I'm calling the method from client and I always get undefined when I resolve `f` with a value on return. I guess I can't receive a promise on client comming from server?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are starting an asynchronous request in the method body. The method returns immediately, and the callback from the request doesn't really have anywhere to return the result.

I don't really know how to do this with methods, but you could do it with publish/subscribe. Something like this:

Server.js

```
var result = "";

Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    request.post('http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/request_token', {oauth:{
            consumer_key: '89hdg8pEoMzRdg',
            consumer_secret: 'dfgdfgHthtdtjtt' }},
        function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var a = querystring.parse(body);
                oauthToken = a.oauth_token;
                result = oauthtoken;
            }
        });
    });
}, 10*1000);

Meteor.publish("goodReads", function() {
    this.added("goodReads", 1, {reads: result});
    Meteor.setInterval(function() {
        this.changed("goodReads", 1, {reads: result});
    }, 10*1000);
    this.ready();
});
```

Client.js

```
goodReads = new Meteor.Collection("goodReads");
Meteor.subscribe("goodReads"); // May be done in waitOn in the router
```

This was taken off the top of my head, and is not tested. It may or may not work, but is at least a pointer to how you could do it

Comment: I will give this a try Suppen